# MVC: Can Partial View has effect of iframe?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, partial-views

I am wondering in MVC(ie 3) + Razor, could we make partial view have the same effect as iframe? For example right side scroll bar, fixed height, etc.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: what is "effect of iframe"? Please explain a scenario you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of CSS `overflow`, `overflow-y` and `overflow-x` properties to achieve the points you gave examples for (right side scroll bar, fixed height), making sure to include a `height` style or even `width` if required.

```
.partial-view-container
{
    height:400px;
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

The possible values for the overflow properties are

- visible (default)
- hidden
- scroll
- auto

So I guess your Razor markup would look something like this

```
<div class="partial-view-container">
@Html.Partial("InnerPartialView")
</div>
```

Further explanation at [css tricks](http://css-tricks.com/the-css-overflow-property/) or [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/default.asp#box)